# Are SQLite reads always hitting disk?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a Pylons application using SQLAlchemy with SQLite as backend. I would like to know if every read operation going to SQLite will always lead to a hard disk read (which is very slow compared to RAM) or some caching mechanisms are already involved.

- does SQLite maintain a subset of the database in RAM for faster access ?
- Can the OS (Linux) do that automatically ?
- How much speedup could I expect by using a production database (MySQL or PostgreSQL) instead of SQLite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, SQLite has its own memory cache. Check `PRAGMA cache_size` for instance. Also, if you're looking for speedups, check `PRAGMA temp_store`. There is also API for implementing your own cache.
2. The SQLite database is just a file to the OS. Nothing is 'automatically' done for it. To ensure caching does happen, there are `sqlite.h` defines and runtime pragma settings.
3. It depends, there are a lot of cases when you'll get a slowdown instead.

Comment: On #2, do you mean that sqlite actually tells the OS not to use the disk cache?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I mean that OS won't “automatically” do anything for SQLite database that it doesn't do for any other file.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Yes, but it's a bit more complicated than that. For example, “read” operation involving subqueries may lead to creation of temporary file on disk every time.

Answer (score 0):

> How much speedup could I expect by using a production database (Mysql or postgres) instead of sqlite?

Are you using sqlite in a production server environment? You probably shouldn't be:

From [Appropriate Uses for Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html):

> SQLite will normally work fine as the database backend to a website.
>   But if you website is so busy that you are thinking of splitting the
>   database component off onto a separate machine, then you should
>   definitely consider using an enterprise-class client/server database
>   engine instead of SQLite.

SQLite is not designed well for, and was never intended to scale well;  SQLite trades convenience for performance;  if performance is a concern, you should consider another DBMS

Comment: The page you linked specifically says that SQLite *does* work well in a production environment up to 100K to 1000K hits per day (or, as they say, 99.9% of web sites).  It's only when you move the database to server separate from the web server that they suggest an actual database server.